# Issue with moving files from localhost to online host

Tags: localhost, hosting, html, window.location

`window.location.href`:
This instruction doesn't work for me on online host and make 404 error, but when I use it on localhost it works properly.
This is the code of instruction :

```
window.location.href= "owghat.php?city=" + strUser  +"&month=" + strUser1 + "&day=" + strUser2 ;
```

Can anyone help me?